# Extract collection elements by index in PostgreSQL? (in comparison to Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

With Oracle, we can use collections such as the `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` array datatype:

```
SELECT SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'c') FROM DUAL;

Result:
ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'c')
```

---

Collections are useful. But in my opinion, there is functionality missing: the syntax of **extracting collection elements by index** is not supported in Oracle SQL (although it *is* supported in PL/SQL).

For example, getting the first element by putting `(1)` to at the end of `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'c')` fails in Oracle SQL:

```
SELECT SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'c')(1) FROM DUAL;
--                                         
Error:
ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
```

---

I want to ask Oracle to add that missing functionality. I've posted an idea request for it here: [Oracle Ideas: Support extracting collection elements by index in SQL](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4499553/support-extracting-collection-elements-by-index-in-sql/p1?new=1).

I want to improve that idea by showing an example of a database that *does* support that functionality.

Does PostgreSQL support **extracting collection elements by index**? If so, what is an example?

Comment: i think your list is te same as for arrays in postgres and it has a variety of functions

Comment: Postgres only supports arrays (pretty much how the SQL standard defines them) not "collections": `select (array['a','b','c'])[1]`